# Prove that the quotient group is cyclic and find its order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $n$ be a positive integer and $ϕ : Z → Z ⊕ Z_n$ be the homomorphism
> defined by $ϕ(1) = (n, 1)$, Prove that $(Z⊕Z_n)/\text{Im}(\phi)$ is cyclic and find its order.

Here is an argument

We can use the first isomorphism theorem to show that $(Z\oplus Z_n)/\text{Im}(\phi)$ is isomorphic to $Z_n$, which is a cyclic group of order $n$.

To see this, first note that $\text{Im}(\phi)$ is the subgroup of $Z⊕Z_n$ generated by $(n,1)$. We can write any element of $Z⊕Z_n$ as $(a,b)$ for some integers $a$ and $b$, and we have

$ϕ(a) = ϕ(1)^a = (n,1)^a = (na,a)$.

Therefore, the coset of $(a,b)$ modulo $Im(ϕ)$ is

$(a,b) + \text{Im}(\phi) = { (a+nm,b-m) : m ∈ Z }$.

We can define a homomorphism $f : Z⊕Z_n → Z_n$ by

$f(a,b) = a mod n$.

This is well-defined since if $a = a' + nm$ for some integer $m$, then $f(a,b) = f(a',b+mn) = a' mod n$.

The kernel of $f$ is precisely $\text{Im}(\phi)$, since

$f(a,b) = 0$ if and only if $a ≡ 0 (mod n)$ if and only if $(a,b) ∈ \text{Im}(\phi))$.

By the first isomorphism theorem, we have

$(Z⊕Z_n)/\text{Im}(\phi) ≅ Z_n$.

Since $Z_n$ is cyclic of order $n$, so is $(Z⊕Z_n)/\text{Im}(\phi)$. Therefore, the order of $(Z⊕Z_n)/\text{Im}(\phi)$ is n.

Please cheak this or you can give another solution

Comment: *Please* learn how to use MathJax. I have shown you a tutorial before. There's no need to use ϕ; use `$\phi$` for $\phi$ instead.

Comment: It will save you from having to copy & paste all the time.

Comment: No, your argument is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use $\mathbb{Z}$ to denote the set of integers, which is a notation of general agreement in math discussions, I think.

Now, we are to determine $N=(\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_n)/\mathrm{Im}\ \phi$. Observe that $a=(1,0)\in \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_n$ satisfies
$$ na=(n,0)\not\in \mathrm{Im}\ \phi,\ \ n^2a=(n^2,0)=(n^2,n)\in \mathrm{Im}\ \phi.$$
On the other hand, $b=(0,1)$ satisfies
$$na+b=(n,1)\in \mathrm{Im}\ \phi.$$
These two elements together generate $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_n$, so we have found that $N$ is generated by the residue class of $a$ (because the class of $b$ is the same as that of $-na$) and it has order $n^2$. So, the group $N$ is cyclic of order $n^2$.

Comment: I fixed some typos. I hope it's clarified.

Comment: Im not getting  why $ na=(n,0)\not\in \mathrm{Im}\ \phi?$
**My thinking** :$ na=(n,0)=(n, n)\in \mathrm{Im}\ \phi$

Answer (score 0):

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z_n},$ and $ H=\text{Im}~ \phi$, where

$$H=\{\dots(-2n, n-2), (-n, n-1),(0, 0),(n, 1), (2n, 2)\dots\}$$

Define $H_g=(1,1)+H$, and we choose $H_g$ as the generator. Next, we need to show $\langle H_g\rangle=\frac{G}{H}$.

Before we doing this, let's first compute the order for $\langle H_g\rangle$.

It is easy to verify $(1,1)^{n^2}=(n^2,0)\in H,$ and $(1,1)^{kn}=(kn,0)\notin H$ for $0<k<n$.

Therefore, we get:

$$|\langle H_g\rangle|=n^2$$

Next, we show $\langle H_g\rangle=\frac{G}{H}$.

Since $H_g=(1,1)+H\in\frac{G}H, \Rightarrow \langle H_g\rangle\subseteq\frac{G}{H}$. This direction is easy.

For the other direction, take $\forall (a, b)+H\in \frac{G}{H},$ since $(a, b)=(1, 0)^a+(0,1)^b$, and

$$\begin{align}(1,0)+H&=(1,1)^{n+1}+H= ((1,1)+H)^{n+1}\\
\\
(0,1)+H&=(1,1)^{n^2-n}+H= ((1,1)+H)^{n^2-n}\end{align}$$

Then we have

$$\begin{align}(a, b)+H&=(1, 0)^a+H+(0,1)^b+H\\
\\
&=((1, 0)+H)^a+((0,1)+H)^b\\
\\
&=((1,1)+H)^{a(n+1)}+((1,1)+H)^{b(n^2-n)}\\
\\
&=((1,1)+H)^{a(n+1)+b(n^2-n)}\\
\\
&=(H_g)^{a(n+1)+b(n^2-n)}\end{align}$$

Therefore,

$$(a, b)+H\in \langle H_g\rangle\Rightarrow \frac{G}{H}\subseteq\langle H_g\rangle$$